# Join table with its model's default scope in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Currently, we can join 2 tables like

```php
    ModelA::join('table_b', 'table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.a_id');
```

With this approach the default scopes on model for table_b (ie: ModelB) are not applied on query. Suppose the ModelB has SoftDeletes enabled now the above join won't include `whereRaw('table_b.deleted_at IS NULL')`. I know i can manualy add this using following code.

```php
ModelA::join('table_b', function($join) {
    $join->on('table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.a_id')
    ->whereRaw('table_b.deleted_at IS NULL');
});
```

I want to know if there is any method to join so that it automatically apply default scope(s) in ModeB. Something like:

```php
ModelA::joinModel(ModelB::Class, 'table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.a_id');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the `joinSub()` function to join on a subquery. So following code worked for me:

```php
    ModelA::joinSub(ModelB::select('*'), 'table_b', function($join) {
        $join->on('table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.a_id');
    });
```

By using `joinSub()` I can also call other scopes on ModelB like:

```php
    ModelA::joinSub(ModelB::filterThis()->filterThat(), 'table_b', function($join) {
        $join->on('table_a.id', '=', 'table_b.a_id');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Filter out the records on related Model, the Eloquent way -

```
ModelA::with('modelb')->whereHas('modelb', function($query){
      $query->filterThis()->filterThat();
})->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Laravel QueryBuilder doesn't consider Eloquent scopes while running queries.

You can simple use Eloquent instead of Query Builder. With Eloquent it can be achieved like so:

```php
ModelA::with('modelb')->get();
```

Where `modelb` is a `HasMany` relationship defined in `ModelA`.

The above statement will produce the following query:

```sql
select * from `modela` where `modelb`.`modela_id` in (1) and `modelb`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Comment: Eager loading modelb will not filter the ModelA. It will return all the rows in table_a with model_b that are not deleted. I want to filter the rows in table_a that don't have related row in table_d whose deleted_at is null.